# Do Toughness or Vitality help with surviving fall damage?

Tags: guild-wars-2

According to the GW2 wiki, [Falling Damage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fall_damage#Falling_damage):

> Fall damage is proportional to the characters health: if a level 80 and a level 1 fall the same height, the amount taken will be different, but the percentage of health taken away will be the same.

Does this mean that both Toughness and Vitality don't reduce fall damage? Or would Toughness help because it's a fixed damage reduction rather than an increase in HP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toughness only reduces direct damage, rather than indirect damage. As such, [toughness has no effect on fall damage](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Toughness) according to the Guild Wars 2 wiki.

Stacking Vitality will not *help*, but does have an effect on fall damage - since fall damage is percentage based, having more vitality will cause you to take more damage, as you will always lose the same percentage of health from the fall.

Comment: So, Stacking vitality won't help either ? If you have 10k life and fall from a height that kills you, anyone in the game would be dead by falling from that same spot aswell ?

Comment: @Marcello correct - but stacking Vitality does make a *difference* in that you take *more* damage in relative terms due to it being percentage based damage.

Comment: Correct. More absolute Damage since the same percentage in a larger health pool leads to higher absolute HP loss.

Comment: But the question isn't "does it make a difference" but "don't reduce fall damage"? (i.e. maybe clarify with a "won't help but does affect"?)